# Vlookup a value and then compare dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I am wanting to look up a value from a table, than take a date and compare it to the row and find which date corresponds to the date I enter.

```
| Column1 | Effective 1 | Effective 2 | Effective 3 |
|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| abc     | 1/1/2016    | 1/1/2017    | 1/1/2018    |
| cba     | 1/2/2016    | 1/2/2017    | 1/2/2018    |
```

I want to look up colum1 and find for example cba; then want to link a date to which effective date, which is always the date less than. So, if the date I am looking up is for cba and it is 6/7/2017 it would correspond to effective 2 which is 1/2/17.

I have tried index match match and also vlookups with embedded if statements and neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Using structured references (in a Table), the following formula will do what you want.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((INDEX(myTable,MATCH(F2,myTable[Column1],0),0))< TODAY()),INDEX(myTable,MATCH(F2,myTable[Column1],0),0))
```

[image]

The formula uses documented but somewhat obscure features of the `INDEX` and `LOOKUP` formulas.  See MSDN Help for more details:

> MATCH ► find the row that matches the search term in `F2` to use as `row` argument in `INDEX`
>
> INDEX with a `column` argument of `0` ► return the entire row
>
> `< TODAY()` to do the `less than` comparison.  You can use a cell reference instead of you need to.
>
> `1/(...` will return `1` or `DIV/0` errors depending on the comparison
>
> `LOOKUP` where the `lookup_value` is greater than anything in the array will match the last numeric value in `lookup_array` and return the value in the same position in `results_array`